# OpenVPN, protecting computer from private network access

Tags: security, vpn, openvpn

I'm a new OpenVPN user. I'm working under Ubuntu, as a client.

What I couldn't find is if OpenVPN client process gives anyone
on a private network any access to my computer, or if it looks
the same as for my real local network, i.e. iptables (which I'm using
through Firestarter) are in charge of network traffic, and only local
users can see/use services I consciously exposed by allowing inbound
connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firewall (iptables) rules will work.